# I need to format and display specified contents from the URL in webView

Tags: ios, ios6, uiwebview

I am creating an RSS feed app , i need to format the Feeds in webView and display only description .

Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [self.url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                          NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Instead of loading all contents of the specified URL i need to format and display only the "description" of the RSS Feed.
I have parsed my data i only need to format it in the web view .
The code for parsing (prepareForSegue):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];
        NSLog(@"Description : %@" , string);

        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From the question it seems that you require to parse that response first.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.in/search?q=search"]; 
NSString *webData= [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
NSLog(@"%@",webData);
```

This code will store your html page into NSString after getting this, parse this string same like normal XML parsing using html tags and get the required data out of this.

Here is a code to load string back to UIWebView as in HTML format:

If you literally want to load an HTML string, try this:

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><head></head><body><p>Provide your display data here in HTML format</p></body></html>"; // in your case it is description data
[webView loadHTMLString: embedHTML baseURL: nil];
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have parsed my data and now i need to format the feeds to display the "description" alone in Webview .

Comment: Then load the feed formatted data back to UIWebView as an HTML string. Refer updated example in my answer.

Comment: no , I need to format the contents in my URL . Is there any methods that can help me ?